# Error when using powershell with "%%G" and "%%~nG"

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

I'm trying to run the below powershell command in a batch file to replace a text string in all txt files, but I keep seeing the error "a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument" with words from the file names mentioned at the end of the error, like "-" and so on.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO powershell -Command "(gc %%G) -replace 'this', 'that' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %%~nG.txt"
```

If I don't use `%%~nG.txt` at the end of the powershell command and explicitly reference a text file (that doesn't have spaces in the file name) then it does work.

I am sure this is because `%%~nG.txt` at the end is not in quotes (and needs to be because the file names have spaces?) but I don't know what adjustment is needed to fix it.

I have tried putting the final file name in quotes: `"%%~nG.txt"` but that doesn't work, I have tried escaping the 2nd to last double quote character with a back tick so powershell doesn't think the command is ending there but that also doesn't work.

I can't wrap the command in single quotes for other reasons (there's huge long strings of text I am replacing that themselves contain things like single and double quotes, that's all working fine).

Am I mixing batch file variables with powershell commands when that just won't work?

I have also tried with "jrepl.bat" (from here: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) and this should replace all double quotes with nothing in the following example, but it's also not working:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "\q" "" \xseq \f "%%G" /O -
```

That works to replace just about any string, unless it has a double quote then it won't do it, even though there's a `\xeq` option for it and I have set the double quote to `\q` like it says to.

Cheers.

Comment: Do the iteration _in_ powershell and it's correct: `powershell -c "gci *.txt | % { (gc $_) -replace 'x','y' | out-file -encoding ASCII $_ }"` (can replace `gci` by alias `dir` or `ls` if you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

Dave cheers. I managed to finally get it working before I saw your comment.

It took 6 hours of trial and error!

Here's the solution in case anyone else is trying to do this.

This uses powershell from inside a bat file and it replaces the text string in every .txt file next to the bat file:

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace 'old text', 'new text' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

It's said the back tick is used in powershell to escape characters, but in a batch file it gets complicated. I found the percent symbol is escaped simply by adding another percent symbol, whereas the back tick (powershell escape character) didn't ever work for me in a batch file. Double quotes are escaped by using three double quotes (sometimes four are needed, no idea why). Characters like colons and forward slashes don't need escaping. Other characters... I didn't need to replace so I don't know.

Comment: Why start from batch? Doing the whole thing in **PowerShell** is trivial.

Comment: Because I was messing about for hours with ps1 files trying to get it working and gave up in the end.

Comment: I get that. I would have to go back & forth from multiple searches to parse the `.bat` portion of your code. I worked wwith the command prompt when needed, but used VBS for automaton. When you're not under the gun, thake time to "play" at the console. Start by learning the **PowerShell** equivalent for common comands: **`dir /a  ==>  gci -force`**. Type `gci -` and then `tab` your way through all available parameters. Sample file properties: `(gci -af)[0] | select *`. There's a consistency to the language and syntax you'll come to appreciate.